# Pandas dataframe: convert columns into rows of a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
userId  feature1  feature2  feature3  ...
123456  0         0.45      0         ...
234567  0         0         0         ...
345678  0.6       0         0.2       ...
.
.
```

The features are mostly zeros but occasionally some of those would have non-zero values. A single row for a userId may have zero, one or more non-zero features.

I want to transform this into the following dataset:

```
userId  feature  value
123456  feature2 0.45
345678  feature1 0.6
345678  feature3 0.2
```

Essentially, we retain only the features that are non-zero for each userId. So, for userId 345678, we have 2 rows in the transformed dataset, one for feature1 and the other for feature3. userId 234567 is dropped since none of the features are non-zero.

Is this something that can be done using groupby or pivoting? If so, how?

Any other pandas-mic solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magic from `melt`

```
df.melt('userId').query('value!=0')
Out[459]: 
   userId  variable  value
2  345678  feature1   0.60
3  123456  feature2   0.45
8  345678  feature3   0.20
```

Notice using `stack` you need mask 0 to `NaN`

```
df.mask(df.eq(0)).set_index('userId').stack().reset_index()
Out[460]: 
   userId   level_1     0
0  123456  feature2  0.45
1  345678  feature1  0.60
2  345678  feature3  0.20
```

Comment: This was magic, indeed. Is there a generic name to this operation, like pivoting is a standard operation on tabular data?

Comment: @Nik This is reshape , like melt and stack--Unpivots